# How to store the decimal remainder of a calculation in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to store the remainder after casting to a whole number.

For example:

```
int amount = 274 
int numDollars = amount/100;  
//this returns 2 for numDollars, but clears out the .74, and I would like to store 74 to amount
```

Does this seem possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without introducing a new operator, you could subtract the dollars from the amount:

```
int amount = 274;
int dollars = amount / 100;
int cents = amount - (dollars * 100);
```

However, Java, like C and C++, has a "modulo" ("mod") operator that gives the remainder:

```
int amount = 274;
int dollars = amount / 100;
int cents = amount % 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the number you have just computed (`numDollars`):

```
int amount = 274;
int numDollars = amount / 100;
amount = amount - numDollars * 100;
```

Note that this line is equivalent to:

```
amount -= numDollars * 100;
```